# Loading Data into MongoDB using external script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a script, where I am making use of the mongo shell to load in some initial data using the **load()** method. But it seems to fail on the very first line, with the following error

> TypeError: db.getSibilingDB is not a function

Here is my script

```
db = db.getSibilingDB('queued')
db.createCollection('restaurantList')
restaurantListCollection = db.getCollection('restaurantList')
restaurantListCollection.remove({})
restaurantListCollection.insert({
    name:"RestaurantA",
    address: "Cherry Street 14",
    waitTime: "15-20"
})
restaurantListCollection.insert({
    name:"RestaurantB",
    address: "Columbus Street 29",
    waitTime: "5-7"
})
restaurantListCollection.insert({
    name:"RestaurantA",
    address: "12th Street",
    waitTime: "10-15"
})
```

Comment: most likely `db`  of  `db.getSibilingDB('queued')` is not a mongodb database instance, but it's not possible to tell from your example.

Comment: @Jthorpe could you please elaborate, what needs to happen to the db variable beforehand

Comment: @Jthorpe thats all the code I have, all I do after that is use load('loadDB.js') in my mongo shell. I am not sure if anything else must be done before that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a spelling typo in `getSibilingDB`.
That would explain why the db object does not seem to have a function called that.

Change it to `getSiblingDB`, (no 'i' between the 'b' and 'l')

Hope this does the trick!